# Access Database C#, Sharing Multiple PC's

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I have an access database on a network drive, unfortunately it runs slowly on the drive whereas if I move it to my c: and access it from there the speed is lightning quick. But when trying to reference it in code for other users on my PC it fails.

```
OleDbConnection VNcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\PCNAME\\c$\\Test\\VendorBook.accdb");

VNcon.Open();
// sql query to grab data from database
OleDbCommand cmdVendorNames = new OleDbCommand("Select [VendorName] from [Vendors] order by VendorName ASC", VNcon);
// reader command to read the data grabbed from query
OleDbDataReader rdrVendorNames;
rdrVendorNames = cmdVendorNames.ExecuteReader();
// data table to output data grabbed
DataTable dtVendorNames = new DataTable();
// add vendor name column from reader
dtVendorNames.Columns.Add("VendorName", typeof(string));
dtVendorNames.Load(rdrVendorNames);

// for each name found add name to combobox
for (int i = 0; i < dtVendorNames.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // adding column to combo box
    cmbxVendor.Items.Add(dtVendorNames.Rows[i]["VendorName"].ToString());
}
```

Any ideas on why it wont connect even if the permissions are granted for full access to each user on that folder.

Comment: A UNC path starts with two backslashes, not one. Also, you probably want to use an @"" string literal for your connection string to avoid having to double-up *every* backslash.

Comment: like this OleDbConnection VNcon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+@"\\PCName\c$\VB\VendorBook.accdb");

Comment: it still brings no data back